# Navigation in dubai using HERE

Tags: here-api

I want use Navigation service from HERE. I have some questions

1. Can I get complete route information i mean complete geometry
2. Is Park and Ride in dubai service for HERE maps is covered in DUBAI?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you would mention which product you are using, and which version. I assume you use one of the native SDKs ? As a reference, link now iOS Premium (3.x) coverage, since it's the same also for Android: https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/navigable-countries.html

So yes, Emirates are a navigable country and available in HERE Native SDKs for iOS and Android, Premium Edition only, version 3.x.

Unsure what exactly you want to achieve in your second part of the question. So yes, there are also POIs, and multimodal routing available, if this helps.